# Difference between usage of Lim and Lt?

Tags: limits, notation

I was told that there is a difference in usage of notation Lim and Lt when referring to limit of a function.. When do we use Lim and when do we use Lt?
All this long I was under the impression that both of them meant the same thing and were just different abbreviations that different authors preferred.

I tried finding the difference by reading the section on limits from my grade 11 math book (where the concept of limits was first introduced),  Methods of Real Analysis by Richard R Goldberg, Mathematical Analysis by Tom M Apostol. However, I wasn't able to find anything related to the notation.

Please give me an idea or a hint as to when we use the different notations. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of anyone using the notation "Lt" for anything? (And especially a source for the claim that it means something other than $\lim$?)

Comment: I agree with Misha Lavrov.  I have never seen "Lt".  Is that perhaps from a non-English text?

Comment: I am not sure of which exact book uses the Lt notation, but we have been taught to use it in high school (in India).. And actually I don't know a source that mentions this, My lecturer pointed it out that they are different..

Comment: [Similar question](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-most-Indian-mathematics-books-use-Lt-instead-of-lim-as-the-limit-notation) on Quora

Comment: I thought that was the case too, but since my lecturer was particular and asked us to find the difference, I thought that maybe it had a technical reason that I was unaware of..

Comment: Wikipedia cites this for the usage of "Lt" vs "Lim":

>  Aggarwal, M.L. (2021). "13. Limits and Derivatives". Understanding ISC Mathematics Class XI. Vol. II. Industrial Area, Trilokpur Road, Kala Amb-173030, Distt. Simour (H.P.): Arya Publications (Avichal Publishing Company). p. A-719. ISBN 978-81-7855-743-4.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Sixty years ago (!) Lt was often used by my professor (E.T. Copson) and the other lecturers: it was old-fashioned even then, and I don't think I have seen it used since. It certainly meant exactly the same as lim.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification everyone. @MishaLavrov, I was informed that the "Lt" notation is used in ancillary books (like those dealing with of Laplace and Fourier transforms and some books on differential equations). My lecturer gave me a hint that it might have something to do with being able to apply the L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @vvg ,that was actually the prescribed textbook for me in grade 11 and I did show that reference to my lecturer, but I was still informed that there was some difference between the two notations.

Comment: This book: Quantum Theory of Light, Robert Loudon (1973) also extensively uses Lt instead of Lim. See: https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/_/OHspAQAAMAAJ?hl=en (It has Search Inside and you can search for "Lt" to see examples). So, it is not restricted to authors from India.